# How to multiply two columns and have product as another column and PERSIST it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I go about when creating a new table and the columns, to have one column be the product of two other columns and persist it?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
column1 int NOT NULL,
column2 int NOT NULL,
column3 AS (column1 * column2) PERSISTED NOT NULL
)
```

Is this the correct way in doing it?

Thanks

Comment: alter table Test add column column3 as column1 * column2

Comment: Why do you expect column3 to be NOT NULL when column1 and column2 aren't?

Comment: And what benefit do you expect to get from persisting it? The fewer rows on a page due to wider rows will likely outweigh any minor CPU benefit from avoiding the multiplication at read time. There is no requirement for this expression to be PERSISTED to index it.